# Why can't I have both an @client.event and @client.command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When I try to combine a command and an event only one of them works while the other doesn't.

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('I am ready.Let us begin')

@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['Razsamaha.',
                 'Profesor Iks',
                 'Jen Grei',
                 'Shelma']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer:{random.choice(responses)}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('')
```

The first @client.event works in both cases, whether only with the 8ball command or the hello event. The issue is that when I try to run them both (the 8ball command and the hello event) together, only the one of them works, yet on their own, they both work okay. Where am I messing up? I only just installed python today.

Comment: You need `await client.process_commands(message)` in your `on_message` event for commands to work. Can you update your code to show how you are using it?

Comment: it works when I edit it so: 
```
client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    wait client.process_commands(message)
```


```